# Vertical space in lists

Tags: spacing, lists

What is the best way to change the amount of vertical space between items in list environments (globally or locally)?

Answer (score 358, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep} % or \setlist{noitemsep} to leave space around whole list

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}
\item foo
\item bar
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The `enumitem` package also allows you to set the list spacing for a particular type or level of list, or for any particular individual list:

```
\setlist[2]{noitemsep} % sets the itemsep and parsep for all level two lists to 0
\setenumerate{noitemsep} % sets no itemsep for enumerate lists only
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep] % sets no itemsep for just this list
...
\end{enumerate}
```

The `nosep` parameter removes all vertical spacing within and around the list; the `noitemsep` parameter removes spacing from items but leaves space around the whole list.

You can also set any of the spacing parameters to exact values, either globally (using `\setlist`) or locally, using the optional argument `[...]` after the beginning of the environment:

```
\begin{itemize}[topsep=8pt,itemsep=4pt,partopsep=4pt, parsep=4pt]
\item Some text
\item Some text
\end{itemize}
```

To see how all of these parameters work, see the following question:

- [\topsep, \itemsep, \partopsep and \parsep - what does each of them mean (and what about the bottom)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/300340/2693)

The package also allows complete control over all other aspects of the list formatting too.

Comment: This is probably the best package for the job. It accepts key value arguments so you could say `\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=1pt, topsep=12pt, partopsep=0pt]` etc, maybe you should expand a bit in your answer.

Comment: @Yiannis The question did ask for a global change.  But I've added some other examples along the lines of what you suggest.  Thanks.

Comment: Without using this package I can specify the type of item numbering as an optional parameter, e.g. `\begin{itemize}[(i)]`. How do I do this while using `enumitem`? Right now I get an error: `missing endcsname`.

Comment: @Will The syntax you suggest is that of the `enumerate` package.  You can emulate that package with `enumitem` by loading it with the `[shortlabels]` option (i.e. `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}`) But the recommended way is to use the `label` key: `\begin{enumerate}[label={(\roman*)}]`.  See the `enumitem` documentation for more information.

Comment: `nolistsep` is `nosep` in newer versions of `enumitem`

Comment: It would be useful if the answer gave examples of how to use properties like `itemsep`, `topsep`, etc (as per @YiannisLazarides' comment). That seems germane to the original question.

Comment: I do not understand: where do you actually set the new value?

Comment: @gented I've added an example (see also Yiannis' comment), and a link that shows how all of the parameters work.

Comment: I still don't get how to set it globally... Eg, to 1pt for all lists.

Comment: @CGFoX You can use `\setlist` in the preamble to set any parameters globally for all lists of a particular type or particular levels of all lists.

Answer (score 151):

the **least demanding way** to do it (**no further packages or whatsoever needed**) is to define your own environment like this ...

```
\newenvironment{myitemize}
{ \begin{itemize}
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}     }
{ \end{itemize}                  }
```

... and use it like this ...

```
\begin{myitemize} 
  \item one 
  \item two 
  \item three 
\end{myitemize}
```

Comment: This works nicely with the `moderncv` package. (unlike the `enumitem` solution, where distances are changed even by just *loading* the package)

Comment: Doesn't work for me :/

Comment: @leonheess you may have to add 
`\setlength{\baselineskip}{0pt}` to the list of modified lengths from @petermeissner. That worked for me. To my understanding, keeping it inside the `itemize` environment makes sure this lenght is modified only locally, and not in the whole document.

Answer (score 42):

You can use `paralist` package and use any of its 'compact' lists (compactitem, compactenum, compactdesc).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}
\begin{document}
    Regular itemize
    \begin{itemize}
       \item First
       \item Second
       \item Third
    \end{itemize}

    Compactitem
    \begin{compactitem}
        \item First
        \item Second
        \item Third
    \end{compactitem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I do the same with `enumerate`? Is this also included in `paralist`? EDIT: belive it might be `compactenum` as mentioned by Herbert

Answer (score 24):

Load package `paralist` and set

```
\usepackage{paralist}
  \let\itemize\compactitem
  \let\enditemize\endcompactitem
  \let\enumerate\compactenum
  \let\endenumerate\endcompactenum
  \let\description\compactdesc
  \let\enddescription\endcompactdesc
  \pltopsep=\medskipamount
  \plitemsep=1pt
  \plparsep=1pt
```

*or* load package `enumitem` and `\setlist{nosep}`

Comment: For me enumitem didn't work. This little textblock saved my day!