# How to add more space between list items?

Tags: spacing, lists

I have a list. Editor says it shall have more space between items. How to achieve such thing?

Comment: Possible related question that might be helpful: [Vertical space in lists](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10684/vertical-space-in-lists).

Comment: @chl answers to that question seem to focus on _removing_ space between items...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem) package, you can add more space between items as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[itemsep=5em]
\item Foo
\item Bar
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

An `itemsep` of `5em` is obviously insanely big, but it shows what can be done.

If you want the change to be global (i.e. apply to all lists) then you could instead add `\setitemize{itemsep=5em}` to your preamble. But with a sensible itemsep, obviously.

Comment: And if you need all lists of that type to have the same spacing you can use `\setitemize{itemsep=5em}` etc.

Comment: @Alan Ah thanks. Good point. Didn't think about globally changing it...

Comment: According to `enumitem`'s manual, `\setitemize` is deprecated in favor of `\setlist[itemize]`.

Comment: @Raphael Thanks for this! I still have the debian TL09, so my old version of `enumitem` doesn't work if I do `\setlist[itemize]{…}` but in newer versions this will work.