# How do I override the \item spacing

Tags: spacing, lists, itemize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vertical space in lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10684/vertical-space-in-lists)

I have the following list being generated for me:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item
  Introduction (this chapter)
\item
  Yum and RPM in datacenter/cloud operations
\item
  RPM - Indivisible Unit
\item
  RPM - For Developers
\item
  Package Signing
\item
  Yum Configuration Management
\item
  Validation
\end{itemize}
```

How can I override the \itemsep and \parskip without placing it with inthe \begin{itemize}?

Comment: See this answer here: [Vertical Space in Lists](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10684/2693)

Comment: And `enumitem` can be used locally as well as globally...