# How to reduce line space (leading) within an enumerate environment?

Tags: spacing, lists, enumerate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vertical space in lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10684/vertical-space-in-lists)

Enumerated items seem distant from each other by default settings in the `enumerate` environment. How can I change that globally (I've seen other solutions, but needed to know which is the best practise), and more importantly for one single instance of an `enumerate` or `itemize` environment?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10684/vertical-space-in-lists

Comment: I am interested in how to change 'one' instance inside a document as well.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The `enumitem` package provides just the kind of commands that can help.

You can use

```
\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=0mm}
```

to change `enumerate` globally, and something like

```
\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=5mm]
```

to change locally. A complete MWE follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=0mm}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}
    \item one
    \item two
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=5mm]
    \item one
    \item two
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice answer. for whatever reason I found ``\begin{enumerate}[nosep]`` gave me less space than ``\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=0mm]``.

Comment: You can also use negative values. `\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=-2mm]` worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `compactenum` environment from the `paralist` package:

```
\usepackage{paralist}
\begin{compactenum}
\end{compactenum}
```

Redefine the `enumerate`, `itemize` and `description` environments if you want this as standard behavior:

```
\renewenvironment{itemize}[1]{\begin{compactitem}#1}{\end{compactitem}}
\renewenvironment{enumerate}[1]{\begin{compactenum}#1}{\end{compactenum}}
\renewenvironment{description}[0]{\begin{compactdesc}}{\end{compactdesc}}
```

Comment: Compare this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10688/4011, `\plparsep` controls the vertical space between items