# Spacing between number and text in TOC

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, books

[image]I am facing problem for spacing for number and text in TOC.

The are very close after second digit.
Help Please... Sharelatex link is https://www.sharelatex.com/2743925469dskrfjrbsyzc

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany]{book}  %openany is for removing blank page between two chapter
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1 in, bottom=1 in,textwidth=6.52in]{geometry} %to get normal margin, remove textwith length

%###############----FONT----#########################


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[adobe-utopia]{mathdesign}%% ADDED
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%--------------------------------------------
%-----------THIS SECTION IS ADDED FROM IIT-------------------

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}%, amsfonts, amssymb
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt} % related to fancyhdr
%------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[bookmarks,%
            breaklinks,%
            backref=false,%
            pdfhighlight=/I,%
            pdffitwindow=true,%
            pdfstartview=Fit,%
            pdfcenterwindow=true,%
            linkbordercolor={1 0 1},%
            pdfusetitle]
            {hyperref}

\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol} % For multiple column
\usepackage{siunitx} %for SI units

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%ADDED BY ME%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{pifont} %for symbols in text mode
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize,enumerate]{noitemsep,topsep=0pt}%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43743/how-to-reduce-line-space-leading-within-an-enumerate-environment
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\ding{70}}%https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{\ding{118}}
\usepackage{tcolorbox} %%for coloured boxex

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Source: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% 'dedication' environment: To add a dedication paragraph at the start of book %
% Source: http://www.tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2010-June/015184.html            %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newenvironment{dedication}
{
   \cleardoublepage
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
   \hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{0.66\textwidth}
   \raggedright
}
{
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace*{\stretch{3}}
   \clearpage
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Chapter quote at the start of chapter        %
% Source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53380 %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{}% Not necessary...
\newenvironment{chapquote}[2][2em]
  {\setlength{\@tempdima}{#1}%
   \def\chapquote@author{#2}%
   \parshape 1 \@tempdima \dimexpr\textwidth-2\@tempdima\relax%
   \itshape}
  {\par\normalfont\hfill...\ \chapquote@author\hspace*{\@tempdima}\par\bigskip}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%       Colour font of Chapters and sections %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty} 
\usepackage{titlecaps} %http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129677/automatic-capitalization-of-sectioning-headings
\chapterfont{\color{blue}}  % sets colour of chapters
\sectionfont{\color{blue}\titlecap}  % sets colour of sections and each letter of word capital
\Addlcwords{to the of or at in and for from is} % make words in title/section small
\subsectionfont{\color{black}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% First page of book which contains 'stuff' like: %
%  - Book title, subtitle                         %
%  - Book author name                             %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% Book's title and subtitle
\title{\Huge \textbf{Chemical Engineering Notes}}
% Author
\author{\textsc{Dr. XYZ}}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Add a dedication paragraph to dedicate your book to someone %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{dedication}
Dedicated to All Chemical Engineers
\end{dedication}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Auto-generated table of contents, list of figures and list of tables %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\mainmatter

%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% NEW CHAPTER! %
```

\chapter{Fluid Flow}
    \section{Drag reduction is found generally}
 \section{Drag reduction is found generally}
\section{Drag reduction is found generally}
    \section{Drag reduction is found generally}
\section{Drag reduction is found generally}
\section{Drag reduction is found generally}
\section{Drag reduction is found generally}
\section{Drag reduction is found generally}
\section{Drag reduction is found generally}
\section{Drag reduction is found generally}
\section{Drag reduction is found generally}
\section{Drag reduction is found generally}
\section{Drag reduction is found generally}

```
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: Your MWE is neither minimal nor working.  Anyway, there are two ways to adjust this.  First, modify \l@section of \l@subsection or whatever it is that is giving you the problem.  Second, use a package like titletoc to do the same thing using a totally different user interface.

Comment: Your code can not be compiled, but you can use the following macro in the preamble to control the identation in TOC  `\cftsetindents{part_structure}{identation_from_left_margin_in_cm}{identation_from_number_or_icon_in_cm}`, examples: `\cftsetindents{section}{2cm}{2cm}`, `\cftsetindents{subsection}{2cm}{2cm}`, `\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{2.5cm}{1cm}`

Comment: Share Latex Link is 
https://www.sharelatex.com/2743925469dskrfjrbsyzc

Comment: potential duplicate: [How to modify the space between the numbers and text of sectioning titles in the table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33841)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is well-known limitation of standard classes TOCs. It depends a bit on fonts used (because narrower fonts will be less likely to show the problem).

Simplest workaround is to add something like this to your preamble

```
\usepackage{tocloft}

\advance\cftsecnumwidth 0.5em\relax
\advance\cftsubsecindent 0.5em\relax
\advance\cftsubsecnumwidth 0.5em\relax
```

For example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\advance\cftsecnumwidth 0.5em\relax
\advance\cftsubsecindent 0.5em\relax
\advance\cftsubsecnumwidth 0.5em\relax
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{chapter}{11}
\setcounter{section}{8}

\section{Enthalpy Concentration Diagram}

\section{Single stage flash vaporization}

\section{Reflux Ratio}

\subsection{Minimum reflux ratio}
\subsection{Optimum reflux ratio}

\end{document}
```

Without the added lines:

[image]

With the fix:

[image]