# Table of Contents (\tableofcontents)

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm creating a table of contents and it seems that when the subsections go past 9 the text stacks next to the digits. Is there any way to add extra spacing between section number and section title?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33842/264024

Comment: See also this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436063/spacing-between-number-and-text-in-toc