# no spacing in the tableofcontents between number of section and name of section

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, setspace

I'm using the `article` documentclass to write a simple document, but when i compile the code the `tableofcontents` look like this:

[image]

From section "Progetti" there is no space between the number and the name.
The code of the section is the following:

[image]

I already tried to take out the `subsubsection` thinking it maybe was the cause, but the problem persist. I also tried [this method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436063/spacing-between-number-and-text-in-toc) but it add more space between number of section and name but it increase the space between all the sections, correct ones included.
Can someone give me a solution? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What's the main document font and font size?

Comment: I guess you want the suggestion of [Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407542/277964) to the duplicate question.

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of adding commands like `\centering` to the mandatory argument of `\subsubsection*`, I would recommend to reconfigure `\subsubsection*`, e.g., using a [headings package](https://www.ctan.org/topic/headings) like [`titlesec`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) or a class that provides such configurations.

Comment: Please never show screenshots of your code. Instead, create a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your set up and problem.