# How do I change the indentation of wrapped lines in enumeration items?

Tags: lists, indentation, enumerate, apa6

When I use the following document (which uses `\documentclass{article}`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Sample Document}
\author{John Smith}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is a short line
\item This is a short line
\item This is a really really really really long line that wraps around the page and as you can see it goes to the left of the item number.
\item This is a short line
\item This is a short line
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I get the following:

[image: the result of an enumeration using the article document class; text is all left-aligned along the same vertical line]

But when I create a similar document using [this apa6 class](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/apa6):

```
\documentclass{apa6}
\title{Sample Document}
\author{John Smith}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is a short line
\item This is a short line
\item This is a really really really really long line that wraps around the page and as you can see it goes to the left of the item number.
\item This is a short line
\item This is a short line
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I get the following result:

[image: the result of an enumeration using the apa6 document class; wrapped text in an enumeration item is shifted to the left with respect to the first line]

How can I use `\documentclass{apa6}`, and line up wrapped lines in enumerations similar to `\documentclass{article}`? And what code in `apa6` causes this to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design. Presumably the APA requires enumerations to look like this.  If you load the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package, you can get the former behaviour with no other changes.  To get the APA version in the same document you can use the `{APAenumerate}` environment.

Comment: Hmm, why does this document align them vertically: http://www2.yk.psu.edu/learncenter/apa-july-09.pdf

Comment: @notfed Because it's a document *describing* the APA style, not written using it.  There's nothing in that document that describes the format of a list. Anyway, the lists can be formatted as you want them by loading the `enumitem` package.  You can control all aspects of the list format easily.  See e.g. [Vertical space in lists](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10684/2693).

Comment: I suppose you're right.  You'd think the least they could do for a quick reference is show APA6 by *example*.