# Reduce spacing between items

Tags: spacing, lists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vertical space in lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10684/vertical-space-in-lists)

Please, how can I reduce spacing between items ?

```
\begin{itemize}

\item[\textbullet]  first
\item[\textbullet]  second
\item[\textbullet] third

\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `enumitem` package and set the `itemsep` parameter to some suitable value. E.g., to have *no extra spacing* between items (whether bulleted, enumerated, or otherwise styled), you'd type

```
\setlist{itemsep=0pt}
```

after issuing the `\usepackage{enumitem}` statement.

Comment: Please i have one more question, how can i align the item on the left, can i use \noindent ?

Comment: @researcher - I'm not sure what you mean by "the item on the left": by default, the items are organized in a vertical list. Please consult the manual of the `enumitem` package (available by typing "texdoc enumitem" at a command line) to learn more about the extensive customization options that this package offers. Alternatively, you could post a new question, with a full minimum working example and not just a code snippet, to inquire about the issue you're trying to solve.