# TexWorks giving error message

Tags: errors, miktex, fontsize, texworks

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme[named=Green]{structure}

\title[Training And Placement Cell]{Training And Placement Cell}
\subtitle{---}
\author{---}
\institute{---}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of contents}

    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}


\section{EXISTING SYSTEM}
    \begin{frame}{EXISTING SYSTEM}
        \begin{block}{}

                \begin{itemize}
                        \item All the entries are done manually.
                        \item Fake entries can be there
                        \item  System is more error-prone
                        \item Difficult to manage data of students
                \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}

\section{PROPOSED SYSTEM}
    \begin{frame}{PROPOSED SYSTEM}
        \begin{block}{}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Providing platform to different departments to register students for placements
                \item Saves time and workload of triaining and placement staff.
                \item Easy to access.
                \item Avoid Fake Entry
            \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}

\section{INTRODUCTION}
    \begin{frame}{INTRODUCTION}
        \begin{block}{}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item This system provides facility to TPC staff to do 
   work regarding placement of students like: 
   collecting student records, registering suitable 
   students, to check the number of placed and 
   unplaced students, making important
   announcements to all departments.
                \item Helps to automate and simplify the work.

            \end{itemize}
        \end{block} 
    \end{frame}

\section{TOOLS USED}
    \begin{frame}{TOOLS USED}
        \begin{block}{}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item \textbf{FRONT END:} \\Asp.Net 
                \bigskip
                \item \textbf{BACK END:}\\My sql. \\ Microsoft IIS Server

            \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}

\section{PROJECT DIVISION}
    \begin{frame}{PROJECT DIVISION}

            \begin{figure}{}
                \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=.98\linewidth]{image.png}
            \end{figure}

    \end{frame}

\section{ADMIN PANEL}
    \begin{frame}{ADMIN PANEL}
        \begin{block}{}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Admin login \bigskip
                \item Students detail record.\bigskip
                \item Generate list for selected companies.\bigskip
                \item Calculate placement percentage.\bigskip
                \item Make announcements.
            \end{itemize}
        \end{block}

\section{USER PANEL}
    \begin{frame}{USER PANEL}
        \begin{block}{}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Enter detail of each student \bigskip
                \item Update student detail \bigskip
                \item Generate students contact detail for each year and each department.
            \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I am new to LaTeX , and do not know why it is giving an error . I use TexWorks and it shows an unreadable error message like:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 17.

[1{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
No file new_1_project.toc.
[2] [3] [4] [5] [6] <image.png, id=187, 395.97937pt x 237.13594pt>
<use image.png> [7 <C:/Users/intl/Desktop/image.png>])
Runaway argument?
\let \AtEndDocument \@firstofone \@enddocumenthook \@checkend {docume\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \beamer@collect@@body.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> new_1_project.tex

?
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can read more about us [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Just a couple style notes: instead of `\item \textbf{term}\\description`, try using a `description` environment instead: `\item[term] description`; instead of putting a `\bigskip` after every item, try [redefining the space between all items in the list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10684)—try `\begin{itemize}[itemsep=1.2\bigskipamount]`.  (See [Consistent Typography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29840).)

Comment: @SeanAllred Thanks ! I will keep this mind while doing my work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admin panel, `frame` is not closed.

```
\section{ADMIN PANEL}
    \begin{frame}{ADMIN PANEL}
        \begin{block}{}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Admin login \bigskip
                \item Students detail record.\bigskip
                \item Generate list for selected companies.\bigskip
                \item Calculate placement percentage.\bigskip
                \item Make announcements.
            \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}  % <------ MISSING
```

Comment: Oh!!! Such a silly mistake! Big thanks ! Was stuck on this for about 15 minutes . Error messages weren't also useful.

Comment: In such a case it is a good idea to add `\end{document}` sequentially after each frame one at a time. Everything after `\end{document}` is ignored. In a case like this, it would help locate the problematic area.

Comment: Ok, thanks , I will keep this in mind the next time :)

Comment: Just writing a feedback from my own experience that just happened (and hence found your question!). I forgot to close }, and it still said it had a problem with scanning frame, where indeed all the framer were indeed closed!

Comment: @Mathmath frame might be collecting its contents in an "unusual" manner, so strange error messages are expected