# How to remove space before enumerate?

Tags: spacing, lists

How can i remove space before enumerate?

```
% before \begin{document}
\usepackage{enumerate}
```

This is first line and i need to remove space between this line and item list below it.

```
% after \begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[-]
 \item asdasd
 \item dsfdsf
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Don't use hyphens for marking items; an en-dash `--` is better.

Answer (score 9):

This is easiest to do with the `enumitem` package.  You can either specify `topsep=0pt` or probably better `nosep` which will also reduce the vertical spacing between items:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
This is first line and i need to remove space between this line and
item list below it.
\begin{enumerate}[-,topsep=0pt]
\item asdasd
\item dsfdsf
\end{enumerate}

This is first line and i need to remove space between this line and
item list below it.
\begin{enumerate}[-,nosep]
\item asdasd
\item dsfdsf
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

To set such an option globally, use `\setlist`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{nosep}

\begin{document}
This is first line and i need to remove space between this line and
item list below it.
\begin{enumerate}[-]
\item asdasd
\item dsfdsf
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

`enumitem` with the `shortlabels` option essentially reproduces the behaviour of the `enumerate` package.

Comment: I need to use enumerate instead of enumitem as i have already coded 6000 lines using this. I prefer not to change this.

Comment: Sorry I wrote `itemize` instead of `enumerate`.  I think my updated solution should do want you want.

Comment: Those approaches didn't work

Comment: @alper Can you be specific?  The code works for me.

Answer (score 5):

some what similar question had been asked before:
[Vertical space in lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10684/vertical-space-in-lists/10688#10688)
a possible idea could be if you want to use `enumerate`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{paralist}
  \let\itemize\compactitem
  \let\enditemize\endcompactitem
  \let\enumerate\compactenum
  \let\endenumerate\endcompactenum
  \let\description\compactdesc
  \let\enddescription\endcompactdesc
  \pltopsep=1pt
  \plitemsep=1pt
  \plparsep=1pt

\begin{document}
This is the first line
\begin{enumerate}
 \item asdasd
 \item dsfdsf
 \item fajfaf
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

With this code result is:
[image]

You can change the vertical length by :

```
\pltopsep=1pt
```