# Why is there so much space under and over my itemize?

Tags: spacing, itemize

I am using a template from somebody else for my master thesis. I have changed the template to fit my needs and everything works, except for the itemize-area. Most of the time there is way too much space over and under it:

[image: Space Itemize]

I have looked and tried many things, like changing the itemize:

```
Dabei werden die Fremdsysteme in folgende Kategorien einsortiert und deren Stärken und 
Schwächen behandelt:
\begin{itemize}\setlength\itemsep{0em}\setlength\parskip{0em}
\item Feedbacksysteme
\item Lernplattformen
\item Microlearningsysteme
\end{itemize}

Zunächst muss jedoch der Begriff "'Microlearning"' definiert werden. Dabei geht es 
um das Lernen in kleinen Schritten und mit kleinen Informationseinheiten
```

But still too much space. I dont know if I am missing a parameter in the template, or using any of the parameters wrong. Any ideas?

This is my main-template (I have omitted the includes of chapters for readability):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{footnote}{chapter}
\makeatother  
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
\parindent 0pt
\topmargin0cm
\clubpenalty = 10000           
\widowpenalty = 10000          
\displaywidowpenalty = 10000   
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\markboth{\MakeUppercase\nomname}{\thepage}
\parskip 1.0ex plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex
\end{document}
```

**[EDIT]:** I cant reproduce the error anymore. I just changed the package `\usepackage{german}` to `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`. Directly after using this, nothing changed (did save, re-compiled, closed my tex-program completely, re-opened, still too much space). Continued my writing, some time later I notice that the space is gone. I had used `\vspace{-0.2\topsep}` before and after my itemize-area, but I can remove it and nothing changes, the space-problem is fixed. I dont know the cause of it, possible that the german-package was the root of it?

Comment: See [How to remove space before enumerate?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148647/4778) - [Vertical space in lists](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10684/4778) - [How to remove the whitespace BEFORE itemize/enumerate?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86054/4778) - [Eliminate space before \begin{itemize}](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1061112/1012553).

Comment: That does look like something that'd be good to fix `:)` But please "minimise" your example. It should contain the text containing the problem itself, and you should remove as many lines in the preamble as you can (especially packages, fonts, and symbols and so on) that are not relevant.

Comment: @WillRobertson: As many packets of LateX are somehow intertwined and connected, I did not know which to list and which not. :(
Also I did remove comments, includes and stuff I thought not to be important to my question. Still too much in it it seems.

Comment: If I add the bit of text you have shown at the beginning, I get nothing similar to your picture; in particular, the interline space is much less in my output than in yours. Please, make a minimal example. Note that the `german` package has been obsolete for several years: do `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` instead.

Comment: @egreg: I switched to the newer package, see my edit. I have removed several commands in my example that I deem to not be the cause of trouble, but cant reproduce the error anymore.

Comment: You figure out which packages to list by removing them and seeing if the error still shows. If not, you need to package. If so, you don't. Doesn't sound like this is relevant now, but maybe useful for next time.