# Vertical Spacing (with enumitem) with Various Levels of Itemize

Tags: spacing, itemize, enumitem

I am currently working around verstical space in lists and changig a bit the spacing. I have come up around this answer: [Vertical space in lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10684/vertical-space-in-lists)

That has worked fine for me with `enumitem` package.

However I am trying to write a two (possibly three) level list. Something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\diamond$}
...
\begin{itemize}[itemsep=5pt,parsep=0pt]
\item item sep \the\itemsep{} and parsep \the\parsep
\begin{itemize}
\item item sep \the\itemsep{} and parsep \the\parsep
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

With output:
[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

As you can see, defining the separation of lines at the beginning of Level 1 changes the separation, but it *doesn't* change it for the Level 2. I want to avoid having to adding the suffix `[itemsep=5pt,parsep=0pt]` at every level, as my list has various items at different levels.

Important for me is that I **don´t want to change it globally (!)** for the whole document (!), as for other lists I still wish the standard values. That´s why something like `\setlist{itemsep=5pt,parsep=0pt}` at the beginning of the document is not helpful.

***Question:*** Can Someone tell me how to use code like the one above which automatically changes the spacing for all levels? (Not just level 1)

I guess the solution lies in creating a personal enviornment like `\newenvironment{myitemize}`, but I am not sure and don't know how to do that.

I would aprreciate any help, many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can define your own itemize etc. environments with `\newlist` and set the spacings for each level individually with `\setlist[myitemize,1]{...}` etc.

Comment: Or globally for all levels with `\setlist[itemize]{ … }`, without mentioning any level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group a \setlist. Or use the before-key to pass values to nested lists:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\diamond$}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[itemsep=5pt,parsep=0pt,
                before={\setlist{itemsep=5pt,parsep=0pt}}]
\item item sep \the\itemsep{} and parsep \the\parsep
\begin{itemize}
\item item sep \the\itemsep{} and parsep \the\parsep
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

Back to the old values:

\begin{itemize}
\item item sep \the\itemsep{} and parsep \the\parsep
\end{itemize}


\begingroup
\setlist{itemsep=5pt,parsep=0pt}
\begin{itemize}
\item item sep \the\itemsep{} and parsep \the\parsep
\begin{itemize}
\item item sep \the\itemsep{} and parsep \the\parsep
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\endgroup

Back to the old values:

\begin{itemize}
\item item sep \the\itemsep{} and parsep \the\parsep
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```