# How do I change the vertical separation of questions in a questions environment in exam class?

Tags: exam

How do I change the vertical separation of questions in a `questions` environment? I need to know how to do it because there are times a vertical separation is not needed, and there are times it is more appropriate (or it looks better) for the exam to have some vertical separation.

I already used the method of using `enumitem` package as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10684/vertical-space-in-lists), but it doesn't work.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question He believed that matter consists of four elements of air, earth, water, and fire.
\question She believed that the children are our future if they are taught well.
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please edit your posting so that it acually generates the issue you're trying to fix. (With a single `\question` item in  a `questions` environment, how can one talk about the vertical distance between (at least a pair of) items?)

Comment: Just stick a \vfill between the questions (or \vspace{1in} for example).

Comment: I'm sorry @Mico. You're right, I didn't realize it :) I edited it now.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, it doesn't work.

Comment: Questions are basically lists, so you could just use e.g. `\setlength{\itemsep}{1in}` _within_ the `questions` environment.

Comment: Interesting, because it worked just fine for me.  How recent is your version of exam class?

Answer (score 1):

I use the following in my preamble.

You can set the `itemsep`aration, `topsep`aration, `leftmargin`s etc, for `questions`, question `parts`, `subparts` and `subsubparts` as well.

```
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0.7cm}%
}

\renewcommand{\partshook}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0.7cm}%
  \setlength{\topsep}{0.7cm}%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0cm}%
}

\renewcommand{\subpartshook}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0.7cm}%
  \setlength{\topsep}{0.7cm}%
}

\renewcommand{\subsubpartshook}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0.7cm}%
  \setlength{\topsep}{0.7cm}%
}
```