# Enumitem settings have no effect on enumerate environment

Tags: lists, enumerate

I've read this question: [Vertical space in lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10684) but neither solution offered there works for me.  When I add this:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{itemsep=-10pt,parsep=-10pt,topsep=-10pt,partopsep=-10pt}
```

Or any combination of the above lots of different things get affected, but it makes absolutely no difference to how `enumerate` environments are rendered.

However, when I add `\setlength\itemsep{-10pt}` to the `enumerate` environment, then it does change the `itemsep` length.

Unfortunately, the LaTeX code is generated, and I cannot alter the generator to insert the setlength command.  Is there any other way to deal with this problem? (Renaming environment isn't also an option for the same reason).

Comment: Could you be more clear on your problem? Maybe a piece of code would help.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, but for others who may run into a similar issue: another code was using `\setenumerate{leftmargin=*}`, which prevented modifying other properties of `enumerate`. After the timer is up, I'll update the post to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact syntax, as documented by `enumitem`, should be

```
usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=-10pt,parsep=-10pt,topsep=-10pt,partopsep=-10pt}
```

or, for specific list levels, something like

```
\setlist[enumerate,2]{itemsep=-10pt,parsep=-10pt,topsep=-10pt,partopsep=-10pt}
```

for an enumerate list of level 2.