# enumerate* - indent issue with next line item

Tags: lists, margins, enumerate, enumitem

I am trying to create a list that would look like:

```
Awards: 1. Award A
        2. Award B
```

I have used the \usepackage[inline]{enumitem} but the result I am getting is the following:

```
Awards: 1. Award A
2. Award B
```

Any ideas on how I can fix that?

The code I have written is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 10in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{currvita}
\newcommand*{\ac}[1]{\mbox{#1}}
\tolerance=600
\begin{document}
    \item \textbf{\textit{Awards:}}
        \begin{enumerate*}
            \item Award A\\
            \item Award B
        \end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you use the  `enumerate*` environment (with a star)?

Comment: Dear @Bernard, yes! To be more precise here is my code: 
`\begin{enumerate*}
\item My first in list.\\
\item My second in list.
\end{enumerate*}`

Comment: Please post a short compilable code reproducing the problem.

Comment: @Bernard

`\textbf{\textit{Awards:}}
\begin{enumerate*}
  \item My first in list.\\
  \item My second in list.
\end{enumerate*}`

Comment: @Bernard I added the code in the original post. I hope that helps. Let me know if you need anything else. Thank you!

Comment: please post a MWE, your code does not include \documentclass nor \begin and \end{document}

Comment: Dear @ebcontrol thank you for your comment. I edited the original post. I hope it is ok now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a KOMA-script class, not so complicated:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{paralist}


\begin{document}

\begin{labeling}{Award:}
\item[Award:] a. Award A
  \begin{enumerate}[b.]
  \item Award B
  \end{enumerate}


\end{labeling}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would place an enumerate list in a minipage. enumerate* formats the list as inline. (replace 0.5\linewidth by something more useful in your full code)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
  \textbf{\textit{Awards:}}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Award A
      \item Award B
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! The question now is, how I can reduce the vertical space between the list items to the default?

Answer (score 0):

maybe it works

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 10in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{currvita}
\tolerance=600
\begin{document}
 \textbf{\textit{Awards:}}\begin{minipage}[t][][t]{0.7\textwidth}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Award A
            \item Award B
        \end{enumerate}
        \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! The question now is, how I can reduce the vertical space between the list items to the default?

Comment: @meletkis if the code is useful please vote by clicking in "this answer is usefull" button.

Comment: I am but I do not have enough reputation yet so it doesn't let me :)

Comment: give a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10684/vertical-space-in-lists

Comment: Thank you very much!