# how to introduce a list of parameters for your mathematical formula

Tags: lists

I am writing my mathematical formula in latex and I would like to create the following list. However, I want to add some more space between the indixes and the definitions and to write the definitions in Italic. How would you do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multicol}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor} 


\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Indices} 
The following indices capture the dimension of the problem:

\begin{itemize}
\item[k]{suppliers, $k\in \{1,…, K\}$}\\
\vspace{-2mm}\item[i]facilities, $i\in \{1,…, I\}, I \subset K$\\   
\vspace{-2mm}\item[o]OpCos, $o\in \{1,…, O\}$\\
\vspace{-2mm}\item[j]customers, $j\in \{1,…, J\}, J \subset O$\\
\vspace{-2mm}\item[p]products, $p\in \{1,…, P\}$\\
\vspace{-2mm}\item[g]transportation modes, $g\in \{1,…, G\}$\\
\vspace{-2mm}\item[y]years, $y\in \{1,…, Y\}$\\
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: package `glossaries`

Comment: Hi @AlessandroCuttin, can you further specify how the glossary pack would be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the space between the items, you could use `\itemsep` command directly after the `begin` opening the list environment.

For italics, you could either enclose your labels with `$$` that would turn them to math mode. Or use `enumitem` package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\setlist[itemize]{font=\normalfont\itshape\space} 

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\itemsep-2mm
\item[k]{suppliers, $k\in \{1,…, K\}$}\\
\item[i]facilities, $i\in \{1,…, I\}, I \subset K$\\   
\item[o]OpCos, $o\in \{1,…, O\}$\\
\item[j]customers, $j\in \{1,…, J\}, J \subset O$\\
\item[p]products, $p\in \{1,…, P\}$\\
\item[g]transportation modes, $g\in \{1,…, G\}$\\
\item[y]years, $y\in \{1,…, Y\}$\\
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

Comment: How can we set the distance between items equal to the space between lines in the text?

Comment: Hi Katatonia, welcome to TeX.SX! Usualy I would recommend that you open a new question if you have one - because this is what this site is all about: asking questions, and getting answers. Your question is a good one and should be on the page. However, someone already asked something quite similar and the answer is in here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10689/90297. I would recommend searching for things like "itemize spacing" in the TeX.SX search line next time.