# List of mathematical parameters

Tags: lists, glossaries

I would like to write a long list of mathematical parameters with their respective definition in Latex (see picture). I have tried different options (adding it as a table, adding them as a glossary), but none of them seems to properly work. As you can see, the list is quite long and it will cover two different pages. Furthermore, I would like to avoid that the width of the list is longer than the right margin of the text. Finally, the left part of the list should not be aligned with the text line.

I would be extremely grateful if someone can help me with this! Thank you in advance!

For the indixes, I put them as a table, which seems to work:

```
\renewcommand{\nomname}{\subsubsection{Indices}}
\vspace{-20mm}
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{The following indices capture the dimension of the problem}
\mbox{}

\nomenclature{$k$}{ suppliers, $k\in \{1,…, K\}$}
\nomenclature{$i$}{ Minimum volume required on facility i [M cans]}

\printnomenclature



\renewcommand{\nomname}{\subsubsection{Parameters}}
\vspace{-20mm}
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{The following product flow related parameters are used}
\mbox{}

\nomenclature{$Q_i$}{ Available capacity on facility i [M cans]}
\nomenclature{$V_i$}{ Minimum volume required on facility i [M cans]}

\printnomenclature
```

I tried to write it as a nomenclature, but since I want to make subsubsections for each of the lists (i.e., one for indixes, one for parameters, and one for variables), the nomenclature does not seem to work. I hope this helps!

[image: The layout I would like to obtain]

Comment: Since you have already posted a very similar question yesterday you could at the very least provide some code.

Comment: What exactly does "but none of them seems to properly work" mean in this context? What exactly (please show the code) did you try so far an which of your requirements was not met when using this code? What is the problem with the code in the [answer to your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/560061/134144)?

Comment: This kind of list is called nomenclature, so have a look [here](https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/nomenclatures) and see if it works for you.

Comment: I added some extra explanation and I added the code of the indixes. I hope this helps!

Comment: The nomenclature seems quite good, but it appears with a "Nomenclature" title which I do not want to appear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I think I have what you want. Take a look:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}


\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\mathgl}[2]{
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{name={#1},description={#2}}
    \begin{description}[labelwidth=1cm]
      \item[\gls{#1}]#2
    \end{description}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First section}

Here you have the first section with some introduction bla bla bla

\subsection{First subsection of the first section}

Now you have some formula here, with some parameters you want to describe\\

The first formula is: $Q_i * \varepsilon = 2V_i$\\

Probably, you will have more text here with some explanations about the formulas and its meaning and more blablabla\\

And here comes a second formula like $F_{c_i}^{\frac{1}{2}} + 1 = 2^{V_i}$

\subsubsection{Glossary of the 1.1}
\paragraph{The following product flow related parameters are used:\\}

\mathgl{$Q_i$}{Available capacity on facility $i$ [M cans]}
\mathgl{$V_i$}{Minimum volume required on facility $i$ [M cans]}
\mathgl{$F_{c_i}$}{Fixed cost of each facility $i$}

\subsection{Second subsection of the first section}

The formula here is: $L_c + 2^{Q_i} = V_c$

And you make a new subsubsection glossary for these parameters

\subsubsection{Glossary of the 1.2}
\paragraph{The following product flow related parameters are used:\\}

\mathgl{$Q_i$}{Available capacity on facility $i$ [M cans]}
\mathgl{$V_c$}{Transportation variable costs}
\mathgl{$L_c$}{Transportation fixed costs}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

And it will produce:

[image]

Comment: You just need to change "Glossary of the 1.1" to "Parameters of 1.1". Let me know if that's what you were looking for¡

Comment: thank you very much. I implemented that, however, I do not get a fixed space between the math symbol and its definitions. I just copied your formulation so I do not know why it is not working. Secondly, I have some long definitions, which will occupy two lines. The second line starts under the math symbol, which does not look good. I think these two problems are the same (I need to fix the space between the math symbol and the definition).

Comment: Try with labelwidth=2em, that worked for me

Comment: I already fixed the same problem by increasing the [labelwidth=1cm]. However, the long definitions still start in the second line under the math symbol. Do you know how I could solve this?

Comment: If I write 2em, the distances disappear (I use 2cm instead). However, the long definitions still appear under the math symbol...

Answer (score 2):

Following what @thewaywewalk said, you can simply make:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

%You can change the title of Nomenclature section this way
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Parameters}

\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{The following product flow related parameters are used}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortisfacilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdie...

\subsection{First subsection}

\clearpage
\mbox{}

\nomenclature{$Q_i$}{Available capacity on facility i [M cans]}
\nomenclature{$V_i$}{Minimum volume required on facility i [M cans]}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

to obtain:

[image]

in page one, and:

[image]

in page two.

Comment: thank you for your reply! It works, nevertheless, I would like to make the title of the nomenclature as a \subsubsection. Is this possible?

Comment: Nomenclature, as glossaries, is considered an apart section, because it contains extra information from the entire document, not just information from one subsection. By the way, I've updated my answer to show how to include Nomenclature in the TOC

Comment: Thank you for your reply! If I correctly understood, I cannot use the nomenclature in between my text, right?  I want to make a list of indices, parameters and variables in between my text. Therefore, glossaries and nomenclatures does not seem a good option.

Comment: I will make a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

As most commentators, I am not quite sure, what you are looking for exactly, but maybe the `longtable` package solves a part of your issues.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|}
                \caption{A simple longtable example}
                \hline
                \textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
                \hline
                \endfirsthead
                \multicolumn{4}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}}
                \hline
                 \textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
                \hline
                \endhead
                \hline 
                \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
                \endfoot
                \hline
                \endlastfoot
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
            \end{longtable}
        \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

I copied this example from this blog post: https://texblog.org/2011/05/15/multi-page-tables-using-longtable/

On a side note: I see you are using units such as kilometre and kilogram, note that in science these are by convention lower case. To make this consistent in your document I highly advise you use the `siunitx` package. And possible even the `mhchem` package for your CO2's as \ce{CO2}, to obtain the subscript 2.