# How to reduce the vertical empty space height/space of the center environment with huge text?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, vertical-spacing

[This famous question explains](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136050/98645) how you can reduce the empty useless spacing between listings or so, but now I'd like to do the same with `center`, which also has a big space here:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\parskip3mm
\parindent0mm % if you want to have no lineskip

\usepackage{roboto} % font

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]:

\begin{center}
    \huge
    \robotoMedium{OBJECTION}
\end{center}

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: preview]

My aim is that it should read similar as if it was nearly one sentence, i.e.

> Here I am describing my:
> **Objection**

I.e. the new line, size and centering should just be some highlighting, but not indicate a new paragraph e.g.

### Tries

Of course I already tried the same solution as explained in the linked SE answer:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\parskip3mm
\parindent0mm % if you want to have no lineskip

\newenvironment{centerCompact}
{ \begin{center}
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}     }
{ \end{center}                  } 


\usepackage{roboto} % font

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]:

\begin{centerCompact}
    \huge
    \robotoMedium{OBJECTION}
\end{centerCompact}

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

It improves the situation a bit, but does not fully solve it:
[image: preview 2]

It's still too much.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you comment that you do not want it to appear as a separate paragraph, but you are explicitly marking a paragraph break before and after the centered text (which adds extra vertical space amongst other things) so removing that helps.

Then `center` is a one item list and lists are set off with `\topsep` vertical spacing so setting that to 0pt makes a tighter display.

Alternatively, for single line entries as shown in the second form you can keep it all in the same paragraph at the tex level using `\\`  rather than a display environment, and centering with `\makebox`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\parskip3mm
\parindent0mm % if you want to have no lineskip ??? (this doesn't affect \lineskip)

\usepackage{roboto} % font
\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]:
\begin{center}
    \huge
    \robotoMedium{OBJECTION}
\end{center}
\lipsum[1]:\\[5pt]
\makebox[\textwidth]{\Huge\robotoMedium{OBJECTION}}\\
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can use `\vspace` to workaround that, I just doubt it is the best solution:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\parskip3mm
\parindent0mm % if you want to have no lineskip

\usepackage{roboto} % font

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]:

\begin{center}
    \vspace{-20pt}
    \huge
    \robotoMedium{OBJECTION}
    \vspace{-10pt}
\end{center}

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: preview]