# How to add a new line in item list

Tags: line-breaking, enumerate

If an `\item` (in `\begin{enumerate`) contains a long line, I need to add a linebreak so the rest goes to another line (but with the same enumeration number). In the following code, I add `\allowbreak` in hoping to break the rest into a new line, but it does not work. How do I do it? Thanks.

```
\begin{enumerate}   
\item  $T(\phi_{1}(x)\barwedge\left(\phi_{2}(y)\veebar\phi_{3}(z)\right))\,=\,T(\left(\phi_{1}(x)\barwedge\phi_{2}(y) \right) \veebar\left(\phi_{1}(x)\barwedge\phi_{3}(z)\right))$, \quad\allowbreak $T(\phi_{1}(x)\veebar \left(\phi_{2}(y)\barwedge\phi_{3}(z)\right))\,=\, T(\left(\phi_{1}(x)\veebar\phi_{2}(y)\right)\barwedge \left(\phi_{1}(x)\veebar\phi_{3}(z)\right))$.
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Adding  a blank line will start a new paragraph with the same enumeration in text mode? In math mode, you need to start a new `$ $` and manually break the lines, or use display mode.

Comment: Note that the text that follow an \item in not an argument of \item.  \item simply starts a new paragrpah and adds a label (inside the new left margin).  You can have multiple paragraphs following one \item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a linebreak, you can add that with `\\` instead of `\quad\allowbreak`.

If you want to have two list items with the same number, you can set it using `\item\setcounter{enumi}{1}` where "1" should be a number one less than what you would like.

Here's an MWE with all both options:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}   
\item  $T(\phi_{1}(x)\barwedge\left(\phi_{2}(y)\veebar\phi_{3}(z)\right))\,=\,T(\left(\phi_{1}(x)\barwedge\phi_{2}(y) \right) \veebar\left(\phi_{1}(x)\barwedge\phi_{3}(z)\right))$\\$T(\phi_{1}(x)\veebar \left(\phi_{2}(y)\barwedge\phi_{3}(z)\right))\,=\, T(\left(\phi_{1}(x)\veebar\phi_{2}(y)\right)\barwedge \left(\phi_{1}(x)\veebar\phi_{3}(z)\right))$.
\end{enumerate}

\hrule

\begin{enumerate}   
\item\setcounter{enumi}{0} $T(\phi_{1}(x)\barwedge\left(\phi_{2}(y)\veebar\phi_{3}(z)\right))\,=\,T(\left(\phi_{1}(x)\barwedge\phi_{2}(y) \right) \veebar\left(\phi_{1}(x)\barwedge\phi_{3}(z)\right))$
\item $T(\phi_{1}(x)\veebar \left(\phi_{2}(y)\barwedge\phi_{3}(z)\right))\,=\, T(\left(\phi_{1}(x)\veebar\phi_{2}(y)\right)\barwedge \left(\phi_{1}(x)\veebar\phi_{3}(z)\right))$.
\item This is the third item
\item This is the fourth item
\end{enumerate}

\hrule

\begin{enumerate}  
\item This is the first item
\item This is the second item 
\item\setcounter{enumi}{2} $T(\phi_{1}(x)\barwedge\left(\phi_{2}(y)\veebar\phi_{3}(z)\right))\,=\,T(\left(\phi_{1}(x)\barwedge\phi_{2}(y) \right) \veebar\left(\phi_{1}(x)\barwedge\phi_{3}(z)\right))$
\item $T(\phi_{1}(x)\veebar \left(\phi_{2}(y)\barwedge\phi_{3}(z)\right))\,=\, T(\left(\phi_{1}(x)\veebar\phi_{2}(y)\right)\barwedge \left(\phi_{1}(x)\veebar\phi_{3}(z)\right))$.
\item This is the fourth item
\item This is the fifth item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I've included two version of the `\setcounter\enumi{}` option to give you a better idea of how it works.

[image]

Comment: Use the enumitem package. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10684/vertical-space-in-lists