# Reducing item separation with easylist

Tags: spacing, lists, easylist

Using `\itemize` I can [easily adjust the vertical spacing between items](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10684/vertical-space-in-lists)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{noitemsep}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item foo
  \begin{itemize}
    \item bar
    \item baz
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

% items are nice and tight :)

\end{document}
```

However this does not work with `easylist`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[at]{easylist}
\setlist{noitemsep}

\begin{document}

\begin{easylist}[itemize]
@ foo
@@ bar
@@ baz
\end{easylist}

% items are still separated :(

\end{document}
```

Comment: please test your examples before you post them.

Comment: `easylist` doesn't use `enumitem` keys.

Comment: Good call @UlrikeFischer, now I am able to reproduce the issue using my examples.

Comment: @egreg what is the implication?

Comment: it means that you will have to use options and commands described in the easylist documentation, e.g. Space.

Answer (score 2):

Since `easylist` sets up its own lists, specifying options for `enumitem` is useless.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[at]{easylist}

\begin{document}

\begin{easylist}[itemize]
\ListProperties(Space=0pt,Space*=0pt)
@ foo
@@ bar
@@ baz
\end{easylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The package has a few predefined styles, but doesn't allow for defining new ones. You can have a look for `\NewList` in the manual for more.